# How to send key events from an app to other apps in Chrome OS?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, ime, google-chrome-os

I'm trying to create a virtual keyboard for general purposes that should stay always on top and send key events to other windows.
I've tried connecting an app that stays on top with the key buttons and a chrome extensions that receives the the letter pressed and tries sending the input with this:

```
chrome.input.ime.sendKeyEvents({
        contextID: context_id,
        keyData: [e, e2]
    }, function() {
        console.log("callback");
    });
```

but the issue I'm having is that when I touch the key on my virtual keyboard the context of the IME gets unfocused and my extension crashes.

Any clues on how to get the virtual keyboard working with this or any other approach?

Comment: Have you checked your manifest version and Chrome OS version? Are you running your code as Content Script? If yes, chrome.input.ime API must operate from the background script.

Comment: It is manifest 2, chrome OS version is 69, the code is running on the background. The keyboard is running as an app and the code with  chrome.input.ime is running as an extension.